# UIPATH - refreshing a single query

Tags: excel, hotkeys, uipath

I'm trying to refresh a specific excel query from UIPATH but can't figure out.

I find an activity called "UiPath.Excel.Activities.Business.RefreshDataConnectionX" on UIPATH official website but for some reason (probably because I don't have the last version) I can't find it in my software ...

I can't update uipath at the moment so I have to find another way to do it.
So I'm trying to do it with the Excel hotkeys ribbon and some click activity, it's not very optimal but this is the only solution I found so far.
Sadly I don't know what's the combinaison is when the indice is "PS" or "PT" or "PR" so I'm stuck again.

any help ?

Comment: If it's just refreshing a set of query results it may be easier to use an Invoke VBA activity instead and have that perform the refresh for you

Comment: Sadly I can't use VBA in this Excel file (company policy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RefreshDataConnectionX is a StudioX activity. You can access it by selecting "**Show StudioX**" when filtering activities in the Activities window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this tip Scott, I didn't know it was possible. but I have to update my UIPATH version or some packets to get it I guess.

Comment: In the main menu, select "Manage Packages". Then, in the Project Dependencies section, you should be able to upgrade your packages to the latest version.

Comment: I can't .... my company policy don't allow me to update anything by myself. I will check my IT referent. thanks for the help.